# How Do I Vertically and Horizontally Center a Multicolumn Which is Part of a row With a 3 Line High Paragraph Cell

Tags: tables, align, multicolumn

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{table}
    \small
    \caption{IT Administrators}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.25cm}  l l l l}
    Logon Name & {\footnotesize Jordan Orb\par} & {\footnotesize James Irving\par} & {\footnotesize Connor Green\par} & {\footnotesize George Gakpetor\par}\\
    \\
    Given Name & Jordan & James & Connor & George \\
    Surname & Orb & Irving & Green & Gakpetor\\
    \\
    Password &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{password\#1}\\
    Company &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Team Dynamix}\\
    \\
    Office & 443.1 & 443.2 & 443 & 723  \\
    {\footnotesize Phone Number\par} & (306)552-5531 & (306)552-5532 & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{(306)552-1124 ext 23} & (306)719-9704 \\
    Email Address & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{{\footnotesize J.Orb \newline @teamdynamix.ca\par}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{{\footnotesize J.Irving \newline @teamdynamix.ca\par}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{{\footnotesize C.Green \newline @teamdynamix.ca\par}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{{\footnotesize G.Gakpetor \newline @teamdynamix.ca\par}} \\

    Title &  \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{{\footnotesize IT Coordination Supervisor\par}} &\multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{{\footnotesize Senior IT  Administrator\par}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{{\footnotesize Junior IT Administrator\par}} &\multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{{\footnotesize Vice President IT  Administration \par}}\\

    {\footnotesize Department, Organizational Unit, Group\par} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{IT Administrators} \\

    City & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Regina}\\
    Address& \multicolumn{4}{c}{1621 Albert St, Regina, SK S4P 2S5}\\
    Country& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Canada}\\
    Enabled& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Yes}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

this produces this:
[image]

I want the IT Administrators cell to vertically center along the center of Department, Organizational Unit, Group

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not show only code snippet, make it compilable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `makecell` and `booktabs`,simplifying your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, tabularx, makecell}
\newcommand{\nl}{\newline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \small\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \renewcommand{\defaultaddspace}{2ex}
  \renewcommand{\cellset}{\footnotesize}
  \caption{IT Administrators}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{2.25cm} *{4}{>{\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
    Logon Name & \footnotesize Jordan Orb\ & \footnotesize James Irving & \footnotesize Connor Green & \footnotesize George Gakpetor \\
    \addlinespace
    Given Name & Jordan & James & Connor & George \\
    Surname & Orb & Irving & Green & Gakpetor \\
    \addlinespace
    Password & \multicolumn{4}{c}{password\#1} \\
    Company & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Team Dynamix} \\
    \addlinespace
    Office & 443.1 & 443.2 & 443 & 723 \\
    \footnotesize Phone Number & (306)552-5531 & (306)552-5532 & (306)552-1124 ext 23 & (306)719-9704 \\
    \addlinespace
    Email Address & \footnotesize J.Orb \nl @teamdynamix.ca & \footnotesize J.Irving \newline @teamdynamix.ca & \footnotesize C.Green \nl @teamdynamix.ca & \footnotesize G.Gakpetor \nl @teamdynamix.ca \\
    \addlinespace
    Title & \footnotesize IT Coordination\nl Supervisor & \footnotesize Senior IT\nl Administrator & \footnotesize Junior IT\nl Administrator & \footnotesize Vice President IT\nl Administrator \\
    \addlinespace
    \makecell[lc]{\footnotesize{}Department, \\ Organizational \\Unit, Group} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\makecell{IT Administrators}} \\
    \addlinespace
    City & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Regina} \\
    Address & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1621 Albert St, Regina, SK S4P 2S5} \\
    Country & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Canada} \\
    Enabled & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Yes} \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- for vertical centering text in cell instead `p{...}` use `m{...}` column type from package `array`
- newer put float environment inside `\begin{center} ...\end{center}`
- you not provide any information about page layout, so the paper size and text width is not known. they are important at selecting font size (used mix of `\small` and `\footnotesize` font sizes is not recommendable)
- use of `\makecell` package and macro simplified table code

**edit:** after edited question i suggest also to do:

- use of `tabular*` environment for adjusting table width to text width
- left to latex to determine size if `\tabcolsep` (distance between columns)
- use only `\small` font size
- slightly increase width of the first column:
- use `geometry` package for define page layout

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
        margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\caption{IT Administrators}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}m{2.5cm}  l l l l}
Logon Name & { Jordan Orb} & { James Irving} & { Connor Green} & { George Gakpetor}\\
\\
Given Name & Jordan & James & Connor & George \\
Surname & Orb & Irving & Green & Gakpetor\\
\\
Password &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{password\#1}\\
Company  &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Team Dynamix}\\
\\
Office & 443.1 & 443.2 & 443 & 723  \\
{ Phone Number}
    & (306)552-5531 & (306)552-5532 & (306)552-1124 & (306)719-9704 \\
    &               &               &    ext 23     &               \\
Email Address & \makecell[t]{ J.Orb \\ @teamdynamix.ca}
        & \makecell[t]{ J.Irving \\ @teamdynamix.ca}
        & \makecell[t]{ C.Green \\ @teamdynamix.ca}
        & \makecell[t]{ G.Gakpetor \\ @teamdynamix.ca} \\

Title &   \makecell[t]{ IT Coordination\\ Supervisor}
        & \makecell[t]{ Senior IT\\  Administrator}
        & \makecell[t]{ Junior IT\\ Administrator}
        & \makecell[t]{ Vice President IT\\  Administration}\\
{ Department, Organizational Unit, Group}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{IT Administrators} \\

City    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Regina}\\
Address & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1621 Albert St, Regina, SK S4P 2S5}\\
Country & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Canada}\\
Enabled & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Yes}
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. Some questions. Why not begin center? Also thank you on showing me a nicer way to format  the code. Your way is wider than normal text block, how can i center it on page?

Comment: float had never be in fixed environments as are `minipage`, `parbox` etc since than they can not float. you should receive at least warning when you compile your code. for centering table in the float serve command `\centering`  after `\begin{table}`, so table is centered on the page, however, text width is probably to small.

Comment: \centering is used and the table still starts too far left of the margin? am i do something wrong?

Comment: @orb, see edited answer. it is slightly changed (since now the font size is known). i suggest to use `geometry` package. used option `showframe` is only for test (it show page layout), in real document had to be removed. us you can see, table is perfectly horizontally centered in text area.

Comment: i got it to work with the changepage package but your formatting has helped immensely

Comment: @orb, than is time to decide which one from receiver answers on the best way solve your problem and accept it :-)